# How to convert an rails initializer into a module or concern

Tags: ruby-on-rails, module

I have a set of authentication functions that I have right now in an initializer.  This means every time I need to make a change or debug I need to restart my development server to see the changes.  I guess it's high time to put the code somewhere more dynamic.  My thought is a module.  Trouble is I use the functions both in a controller and in views.  I think I can get the functions included into the controller but they show as undefined methods in views.  Can someone tell me the rails way to do this?

The auth mechanism is looking for a cookie set from an legacy PHP system to avoid a second login for the new code done in Rails.

Everything works great as an initializer.  To covert to a module I just wrapped the initializer code in `module BtrSSO`, moved it to the lib folder, and then started including it in controllers.

config/initializers/btr_sso.rb

```
  def logoutSSO
    cookies.delete :BTR_SSO
    session[:sso_options] = nil
  end

  def getSSOShop
   return "" if session[:sso_options].nil?
   session[:sso_options][:ediv]
  end

def getSSOUserName
  return "Not Logged In" if session[:sso_options].nil?
  session[:sso_options][:sysname]
end

def getSSOIsManager
  return false if session[:sso_options].nil?
  session[:sso_options][:is_mgr]==true
end

def setSSO(employee)
  #logger.debug employee.inspect
  return if employee.nil?
  #logger.debug "After employee nil check"
  logger.info "setting cookie with #{employee.sysname} {employee.ediv}"
  cookie_stuff = Hash.new
  cookie_stuff[:sysname] = employee.sysname
  cookie_stuff[:ediv] = employee.ediv

  cookies[:BTR_SSO] = {
    :value => cookie_stuff.to_json,
    :expires => 1.week.from_now,
    ## required on production I think
    #        :domain => 'mydomain.com'
  }
  logger.debug employee.inspect
  #should this be in the sessions controller?
  session[:sso_options] = Hash.new() if session[:sso_options].nil?
  session[:sso_options][:sysname] = employee.sysname
  session[:sso_options][:ediv] = employee.ediv
  session[:sso_options][:is_mgr] = employee.ismgr
  logger.debug session[:sso_options].inspect
end

def authSSO
  logger.debug session[:sso_options].inspect
  session[:redirect_to] = request.path_info
  redirect_to login_path(nexturl: request.path_info) if session[:sso_options].nil?
end

def is_worker_class
  read_cookie
  unless session[:sso_options].nil?
    session[:sso_options][:sysname] == "worker"
  else
    false
  end
end

def read_cookie
  session[:sso_options] = JSON.parse cookies["BTR_SSO"] unless cookies["BTR_SSO"].nil?
end
```

The view calls getSSOUserName which is undefined.

I've tried "include BtrSSO" in the application_controller.rb and in the more direct controller but no difference.

The view is in views/layouts if that makes a difference.

```
!!!
%html
  %head
    %meta{:content => "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0", :name => "viewport"}
      %title= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : "Intranet"
      %meta{:content => content_for?(:description) ? yield(:description) : "Our Intranet", :name => "description"}
        = stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all"
        = javascript_include_tag "application"
        = csrf_meta_tags
        = yield(:head)
        = yield(:javascripts)
  %body{:class => "#{controller_name} #{action_name}"}
    - unless getSSOUserName == "worker"
      = render 'layouts/navigation'
    - else
      = render 'layouts/navigation_worker'
    .uk-container.uk-container-center.buffer-top
      /= render 'layouts/messages'
      = show_flash_messages

      = yield

    = render 'layouts/footer'
```

Another example is in the menubar which tries to show the user name.  This is a fragment in view/layouts

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in module and move the entire file to app/helpers folder:

```
# app/helpers/btr_sso.rb

module BtrSso # Name has to match the file name
   # your definitions here
end
```

Helpers are automatically included in all view context, so explicit `include` is not needed. If you prefer to name your module `BtrSSO`, use inflector acronyms.

Comment: The functions are generally used in the controllers.  I would think if I put it in the helpers it won't work for the controllers.  Looking for a way to do both.  Do you think code in the helpers can get called from a controller (before filter)?

Comment: They can't until you include them in controller, however I do not like this pattern. If those are to be used in controller, write controller's concern and include it within controller. Remember to mark those methods as helpers if youw ant to sue them within the view as well with `MyController.helper_methods :method1, :method2, ...`

Comment: Not sure that I know how to write a proper concern.  Googled quite  a bit and documentation is not great.  Particularly regarding the concept of base.include (necessary or not?)  Any chance you can amend your answer code to show how the concern would be done (with helper_methods)